# Trying to reloadData in visible cells from viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, tableview, reloaddata

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Gives an error : 
**NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0**

I am making a query in background .. as soon as the data is available .. the cells need to be reloaded .. with the new images and data .. i require this only when the app opens , Thus in viewDidLoad .. and the problem with [self.tableView reloadData] is it updates the entire UI giving a flickering effect.

**CODE :**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad



{

[super viewDidLoad];

self.myTableView.dataSource = self;

self.myTableView.delegate = self;



PFQuery * getCollectionInfo = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Collection"];   // make query    

[getCollectionInfo setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    [getCollectionInfo findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {

            CollectionQueryResult = (NSMutableArray *)objects

//                [self.tableView reloadData]; // creates flicker

            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

        }

        else{

           //no errors

        }

   }];

});

}



-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

return 1;

}



-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return [CollectionQueryResult count] ;

}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

// configure cell

    static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CollectionsTableCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[CollectionsTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

}

else {

   cell.cellImageView.image = nil;

}

[cell.collectionLoadingActivity startAnimating];

    collectionInfo = [CollectionQueryResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString * collName = [collectionInfo objectForKey:@"name"];

cell.cellTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",[collName uppercaseString]];

PFFile * collectionImageFile = [collectionInfo objectForKey:@"photo_landscape"];

dispatch_queue_t CollectionImageQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(CollectionImageQueue, ^{

    [collectionImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            cell.cellImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

            [cell setNeedsLayout];

        });

    } progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {

        if ( !(percentDone == 100)) {

            [cell.collectionLoadingActivity isAnimating];

        }

        else if (percentDone == 100){    

            [cell.collectionLoadingActivity stopAnimating];

        }

    }];

});

return cell;

}



#pragma mark - Table View Delegate

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

self.selectedCollection = [CollectionQueryResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];   //to pass on

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showCollectionItems" sender:self];  

}



-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showCollectionItems"]) {

    CollectionItemsViewController * collectionItems = (CollectionItemsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

    collectionItems.collection = self.selectedCollection;

    [segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];

}

}

@end
```

Comment: A duplicate of your other question really. How many rows are there in the section?

Comment: Why are you trying to reload visible rows in `viewDidLoad`? The table isn't even visible yet at this point.

Comment: What [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] returns?

Comment: @Wain .I regret doing it .. but i am really stuck on this from 2 days .. i understood you logically but what do i actually do with it and where in this code is still a problem .. i appreciate your response and request you kindly provide an elaborated solution.

Comment: Why are you using `dispatch_async` in this code? You already have `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` so it isn't on the main thread...

Answer (score 1):

viewDidLoad is a bad place for reloading table view's cells. Move your code to viewDidAppear method.

Comment: While true, this makes no attempt to answer the question. Simply moving the call to `reloadData` may not fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it crashes because you don't have visible rows, first check for this

```
if([self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows].count)
{
// Do something
}
```

**Or if you want to reload without flickering, try below code..**

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```